# Reading cyrillic from Console C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read cyrillic( "Иванчо говори само глупости") from the console, but everything I get is "????". For the first time i write on C++ and I will be very greatful if someone help me to solve this problem.

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<clocale>

using namespace std;

bool CheckLetters(int letter)
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    bool isCyrillic = ('\u0410' <= letter && letter <= '\u044f');
    if ((letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
        || (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')
        || isCyrillic)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    map<unsigned char, int> letters;

    getline(cin, input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char currentLetter = input[i];
        if (CheckLetters(currentLetter))
        {
            map<unsigned char, int>::iterator elementIter = letters.find(currentLetter);
            if (elementIter == letters.end())
            {
                letters[currentLetter] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                letters[currentLetter] ++;
            }
        }

    }

    for (map<unsigned char, int>::iterator current = letters.begin();
         current != letters.end(); current++)
    {
        pair<unsigned char, int> currentElement = *current;
        cout << currentElement.first << " " << currentElement.second <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `wchar_t` instead of `char`?

Comment: no, i will try :)

Comment: no, doesn't work with wchar_t

Comment: you have to use the `w` versions as [`std::wcin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), ´std::wsting´, etc. as well of course.

Answer (score 4):

Unicode is recommended over changing the code page to Russian or any specific language. Windows APIs use UTF16, unfortunately Windows console has limited Unicode support. Here is a solution which is specific to Windows console and Visual Studio (it won't work with MinGW for example). It still won't work with some Asian languages (or at least I don't know how to make it work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h> //for _setmode
#include <fcntl.h> //for _O_U16TEXT

int main() 
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"ελληνικά Иванчо English\n";

    std::wstring str;
    std::wcin >> str;
    std::wcout << "output: " << str << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you cannot use `std::cin` and `std::cout` after changing mode to UTF16. You have to set mode back to `_O_TEXT` if you want to keep using ANSI input/output. Example:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_TEXT);
std::cout << "Test\n";
```

After receiving input in UTF16, you may want to use [`WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) convert to UTF8 (which is stored in `char`) for compatibility with network functions etc.

Answer (score 2):

How about this combination?

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
SetConsoleOutputCP(866);
```

Comment: That's not standard c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is reading text from console. I don't think (not 100% sure) there is concept of "console" or "terminal" in standard C++. Whatever solution is going to have to at least depend on platform specific behavior, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

My main problem was, that I didn't set the encoding in VS in the beginning. So, I make new project and set the codepage to 1251. This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<map>
#include<windows.h>
#include<locale>

using namespace std;

bool CheckLetters(wchar_t letter)
{
    bool isCyrillic = 65472 <= letter && letter <= 65535;
    if ((letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
        || (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')
        || isCyrillic)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    wstring input;
    map<wchar_t, int> letters;

    getline(wcin, input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        char currentLetter = input[i];

        if (CheckLetters(currentLetter))
        {
            map<wchar_t, int>::iterator elementIter = letters.find(currentLetter);
            if (elementIter == letters.end())
            {
                letters[currentLetter] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                letters[currentLetter] ++;
            }
        }

    }

    for (map<wchar_t, int>::iterator current = letters.begin();
        current != letters.end(); current++)
    {
        pair<wchar_t, int> currentElement = *current;
        cout << (char)(currentElement.first) << " = " << currentElement.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to all that gives me advice.