# Convert a string with accents from console in a UTF8 wstring

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, utf-8, wstring

When I enter 'café' in Windows console, in the wide string I got 'caf'
'c' code : 99
'a' code : 97
'f' code : 102
'' code : 130 or other strange values with the stuff I found in the internet,... 233 is the correct value which is the UTF-8 code for 'é'

```
#undef      UNICODE
#define     UNICODE
wstring wstrCharsList;
std::getline(wcin, wstrCharsList);
if (!std::wcin.good()) cout << "problem !\n";
wcout << wstrCharsList << std::endl;
```

I tried ALL the stuff I found on the other SO questions and on the web (especially : https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/) and nothing worked.

I need a wstring encoded with UTF8 to provide it to my API to perform some string comparisons (with strings loaded from a text UTF-8 encoded file.)

NB: On Linux my program works correctly. FU Microsoft.

Comment: `I need a wstring encoded with UTF8` What?! You're trying to store UTF-8 characters in a **wide** string? That's the exact opposite of what it's intended for -- you need a regular 8-bit string for UTF-8, period. On any platform.

Comment: it allows me to do comparisons if the character takes more than one byte... if you can help me to have a UTF8 std::string from console I will handle the rest.

Comment: On Linux everything works with UTF8. On Windows a "code page CP" is used. This CP is UTF7 (ASCII) and the 8th bit is used for 127 extra characters, chosen depending on your System configuration. Internally Windows works with a UTF16 representation ("wide char"). You need to look for some lib that makes the translation between those different representations.

Comment: the problem is just console input :(

Comment: Use `_setmode` to receive the correct `std::wstring`, then compare it with another `std::wstring`. See this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40417293/4603670 - Use `WideStringToMultibyte` to convert UTF16 to UTF8 (but I don't think you need that here). Note that windows console has limited Unicode support for some Asian languages.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I already tried that, stdin with UTF16 doesn't work, after pressing "Enter" std::cin is still executing...

Comment: I fixed my problem by inputing a string via cin and tweaking MultiByteToWideChar.

Comment: It's 2022, my knwoledge has increased then and I have to admit that "UTF 8 wstring" does not mean anything, it's just UTF16 ! correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By tweaking, I found the solution above:

```
const wchar_t * ConvertToUTF16(const char * pStr)
{
   static wchar_t wszBuf[1024];
   MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, pStr, -1, wszBuf, sizeof(wszBuf));
   return wszBuf;
}
...
string strExtAsciiInput;
getline(cin, strExtAsciiInput);
wstring wstrTest = ConvertToUTF16(strExtAsciiInput.c_str());
```

And miraculously 'café' is correctly converted to UTF-8 wstring: 'é' has 233 code ! can anyone expalin to me why this work ? in MultiByteToWideChar when I use the flag CP_UTF8 the output is incorrect 'é' is wrong (2 bytes) but with CP_OEMCP it is correctly parsed and 'é' has the correct UTF-8 code... Seriously WTF ?